# Making GNU indent handle struct literals properly

Tags: c, indentation, gnu

When I try to use GNU indent on this bit of code:

```
tree_node_s *t = GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC (sizeof (tree_node_s));
*t = (tree_node_s){.val = n,.h = 0};
```

I get this:

```
tree_node_s *t = GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC (sizeof (tree_node_s));
*t = (tree_node_s)
  {
  .val = n,.h = 0};
```

Now obviously, this looks pretty awful and isn't clearly a struct literal. I'm passing only default options to GNU indent (meant to be the GNU style). Is there an option I can pass to it to make it deal with this situation in a way that doesn't end up looking quite so horrid?

Comment: I had to report a bug in the handling of compound literals in another formatting program, `uncrustify`.  It was resolved promptly, but it does not surprise me to hear that another program has overlooked the issue.

Comment: I mainly ask this question so I don't look like an idiot when I *do* report this bug!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work somewhat in [2.2.11](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.indent.bugs/1144) at least, but there might be another problem in compound statements outside a block (check out the bugzilla links). If you use an older version, you might upgrade and try again.

Just a suggestion.

Comment: That's the version I'm using - and this causes this exact behaviour.

Comment: I think indent just takes the curly braces as blocks in its (overly?) simplified parser and does not care about the assignment of looks for a preceeding compound statement token (`if`, `for`,...). Maybe using Linux style indentation might look better here, but I suppose that is out of question? (that might have been the style used in the gmame example).

Comment: I don't think this is an issue of which style to use - this is erroneous behaviour, and based on the responses I've seen here, I think I should report it as a bug.

Comment: That's why I said "... look better ...". It was just for the formatting. The actual problem with compound statements won't be solved by that, of course.

Answer (score -1):

if 'tree_node_s' is more than a single intrinsic variable (like int, char, etc) then the posted code will not work properly

This is because assigning a struct from a struct only works when the receiving struct is being created.  In the posted code, the receiving struct is already created, so the proper assignment will not be performed.

suggest:

```
t->val = n;
t->h = 0;
```

Perhaps not quite as elegant, but very reliable.

Comment: That is not a gcc extension, but standard C since C99. Direct assignment is also ok and might just result in implicit memcpy. Your suggestion would have to be modified each time a struct field has been added or (re)moved. Also, the assignment guarantees unspecified fields to be zeroed, while yours leaves them at random values. I would not call this elegant, neither reliable - sorry.